# regular expression inside json

Tags: regex, json

I would like to validate a url against a pattern. 
this is the URL

```
/search?name=john
```

Now, `john` could be any name, so it can be any sting. But, the`/search?name=` part of the URL should remain the same always.

I tried this regex and it did not work for me.

```
^([/search\\?name])=([a-z]+)$"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the square brackets `[]` around the string `/search\\?name`. The brackets are used to define character classes. An expression of the form `[abc]` would not match the string `abc`, but only either of the characters `a`, `b` or `c`. Hence the regex should be:

```
^(/search\\?name)=([a-z]+)$
```

There's also no need for parentheses unless you're capturing subpatterns in groups:

```
^/search\\?name=[a-z]+$
```

Comment: `+1` Thanks it worked. Need some minutes to accept it, meanwhile, I still do not understand why `[/search\\?name]` should not evaluate to true. Isn't that a valid expression?

Comment: The expression `[abc]` would not match the string `abc`. It would match _either `a`, or `b` or `c`_. This expression defines a set of characters that could be matched. See http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. If you're using Java, here's the corresponding [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/char_classes.html)